# Perl mutiple children creation

Tags: multithreading, perl

My program will fork, launching $n children. When a child finishes, the parent will launch a new one, if we have more to launch.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

#function, that every child will run
sub func
# {{{
{
      my $i = shift;
      my $delay = shift;

      print "$i started\n";
      sleep($delay);
      print "$i finished\n";
}
# }}}

#max number of concurrent children
my $max_n = 2;

#number of seconds each child will sleep
my @delays = (8, 5, 5);
my $n_elements = scalar(@delays);

#number of currently running children
my $n;
if ($n_elements > $max_n) {
      $n = $max_n;
}
else {
      $n = $n_elements;
}

#initial children creation
my $i;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      my $pid = fork();
      if ($pid == 0) {
            #child runs the function
            func($i, $delays[$i]);
            exit(0);
      }
}

#any children still running?
while ($n > 0) {
      #wait until one of them dies
      my $dead_child_pid = wait();
      print "$dead_child_pid done\n";

      #do we need to create new children?
      if ($i < $n_elements) {
            #create a child
            my $pid = fork();
            if ($pid == 0) {
                  func($i, $delays[$i]);
                  exit(0);
            }
            else {
                  #move pointer to the next element of @delays
                  ++$i;
            }
      }
      else {
            #decrease number of running children
            $n--;
      }
}

print "parent finished\n";
```

When I run it, it prints:

```
1 started
0 started
```

Here I check the processes:

```
bash-4.2$ ps -A | grep perl
 3433 pts/2    00:00:00 perl
 3434 pts/2    00:00:00 perl
 3435 pts/2    00:00:00 perl
```

So, it created 3 processes: 3433 - parent, 3434 and 3435 - children. Then:

```
1 finished
3435 done
2 started
```

Now again:

```
bash-4.2$ ps -A | grep perl
 3433 pts/2    00:00:00 perl
 3434 pts/2    00:00:00 perl
 3438 pts/2    00:00:00 perl
```

It launched the 3-rd child with pid 3438 after the death of the 2-nd.

```
0 finished
3434 done
2 finished
3438 done
parent finished
```

So, everything seems to be correct with the exception of the reversed launching order of children in the 1-st loop.

Maybe, it's possible to unite children creation from the both loops into a function. As their code has similar parts:

```
  my $pid = fork();
  if ($pid == 0) {
        #child runs the function
        func($i, $delays[$i]);
        exit(0);
  }
```

Do you see any more drawbacks in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some changes,

- only one while looping until children are dead
- new children are launched if @queue has jobs
- waiting for children if empty queue or max allowed forks is reached
- forkit function which takes worker function as first parameter

Most of the time child launching is in correct order, but sometimes as you noticed, they're reversed (`time()` shows time difference for each event)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use Time::HiRes qw/time /;

sub forkit(&) {
  my ($worker) = @_;

  my $pid = fork();
  if ($pid == 0) {
    $worker->();
    exit(0);
  }
  return $pid;
}
#function, that every child will run
sub func {
  my $i = shift;
  my $delay = shift;

  print time(), ":$i started\n";
  sleep($delay);
  print time(), ":$i finished\n";
}

#max number of concurrent children
my $max_n = 2;
#number of seconds each child will sleep
my @delays = (8, 5, 5);

my @queue = @delays;
my @dead_child;

my $active = 0;
while (@dead_child < @delays) {

  if (!@queue or $active == $max_n) {
    push @dead_child, wait();
    print time(), ":$dead_child[-1] done\n";
    $active--;
  }
  if (@queue) {
    my $i = @delays - @queue;
    my $delay = shift @queue;
    forkit {
      func($i, $delay);
    };
    $active++;
  }
}

print time(), ":parent finished\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be improved by using queues as the main construct to convey what is going on.

First, you have a pending queue:

```
my @pending = (8, 8, 5);
```

Second, you have an empty queue with the currently active workers:

```
my @workers;
```

And this queue has a size limit:

```
my $max_workers = 2;
```

This can all be run by a single `while` loop:

```
while(@workers < $max_workers) {
    ... add one more worker ...
    ... remove all workers that are done ...
    ... break out of loop is @pending and @workers are both empty
    ... wait for a worker to exit (or sleep) ...
}
```

When this loop exits, you're all done.